# Merge 3 git repos and being able to push in 2 different repos

Tags: git, github, merge

I want merge 3 git repos with history and then I want be able to push different branch in 2 repos and make merge request to MainRepo.
I have MainRepo, ARepo and BRepo. I want merge ARepo and BRepo to MainRepo as a result I should get new_branch. 
This new branch should be pushed to my privateRepo.
Also I want be able push some branches (which will be created later as a stable version) to publicRepo. Last but not least I want be able make merge request to MainRepo.
It is possible and wow I should configure git project to achive this?

Comment: Do `ARepo`, `BRepo`, and `MainRepo` have a common history or structure? You might find merging them to be an arduous task otherwise.

Comment: They don't. For start I thought about separate them in new project by modules. They all use maven structure. And then start margine code. Main and B repo are github repos, private repo will be hosted on bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'd go with something like this series of commands, in `MainRepo` on your local:

```
> git checkout -b merge-others
> git remote add ARepo https://a_repo.git # Replace with proper URL
> git remote add BRepo https://b_repo.git # Replace with proper URL
```

So far, all you've done is made MainRepo aware of the others. Now do:

```
> git fetch ARepo
> git fetch BRepo
```

Which retrieves the branch/commit info from the two remotes. Then, merge in the appropriate branches from the other two:

```
> git merge ARepo/master # Resolve any merge conflicts
> git merge BRepo/master # Resolve any merge conflicts
```

Finally, you want to push to your private and public repos:

```
> git remote add privateRepo https://private_repo.git # Replace with proper URL
> git push -u privateRepo HEAD
> git remote add publicRepo https://public_repo.git # Replace with proper URL
> git push -u publicRepo HEAD
```

As for making a pull request for `MainRepo`, that depends on your platform. If you're using GitHub it's simple, but I can't speak for other platforms. Good luck!